# how to solve Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

I am new in Asp.net. i want to upload image and save records in Sql Database it caught  "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". I don't know why this error encountered during runtime. Anyone know help me . its very helpful my project

```
 protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    Label2.Visible = true;
                    Label2.Text = "Please Select Image File";    //checking if file uploader has no file selected


                }
                else
                {
                    int length = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                    byte[] pic = new byte[length];


                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, length);
                    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into Student" + "(RegNo,Name,DOB,Gender,Address,Country,CreatedTime,Picture) values(@RegNo,@Name,@DOB,@Gender,@Address,@Country,@date,@photo)", con);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", RegNo.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Dob.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", Gender.SelectedValue);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country.Text);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", pic);

                    try
                    {
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Label2.Visible = true;
                        Label2.Text = "Image Uploaded Sucessfully";
                        con.Close();//after Sucessfully uploaded image
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }


                Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is in this line:

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Dob.Text);
```

You can either convert it using `Convert.ToDateTime()` if it is in the correct date format

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Convert.ToDateTime(Dob.Text));
```

However, if it is not, there is a function called [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) which will convert specified string representation of a date and time using the specified format.

Example, your date is in format `dd/MM/yy` - `31/01/18`

```
string strDob = Dob.Text; // 31/01/18
DateTime dtDob = DateTime.ParseExact(strDob , "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dtDob );
```

Answer (score 0):

MS SQl's default date time format is year-month-day
You need to parse your datetime format to this format
Following code is

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

DOB might be the problem in your code, do

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", Convert.ToDateTime(Dob.Text));
```

make sure Dob.Text is a proper date.

Comment: it display date and time. i want to display only dd/mm/yyyy. Am using Calender

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this because it need to convert with format**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB",Convert.ToDateTime(emp.DOB).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()));
```

It will look like this in the database:

```
11/12/2020 5:32:49 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

(DateTime)(object)(Dob.Text)

it's that simple :)